# Можно служить на алтаре?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Считается также, что апостолы Пётр и Павел не просто бывали здесь
>   <церковь Святой Пуденцианы>. В храме, в конце левого его нефа,
>   хранится ***доска алтаря, на котором служил апостол Пётр***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«...<церковь Святой Пуденцианы>. В торце левого нефа хранится доска из её алтаря, где служил ап. Пётр.»

«...<церковь Святой Пуденцианы>. В левом нефе храма хранится сейчас доска алтарного жертвенника, на котором служил Пётр.»

Comment: И... без вариантов?

Comment: Не на алтаре, — на жертвеннике служат.

Comment: А дальше по тексту вот что выясняется:  ***Апсида символизирует царство чистого духа, а конха – сень над святая святых церкви, над её алтарём. Алтарём, которым в католической церкви продолжает служить саркофаг мученика – прообраз Престола Уготованного.***